# Trying to iterate array of objects PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object

I have a method in which I want to parse input from an SQL-Row into an object:

```
function buildPictureArray($sqlRow) {
   $pics = [];
   foreach($sqlRow as $value) {
      extract($value); // How to do this more elegant?
      $newObj = new PICObject($id, $filename, $thumb . $filename, $full . $filename, $title, $subtitle); // These are column names I got from extract
      $pics[] = $newObj;
   }
   return $pics;
}
```

My PICObject looks like this:

```
  Class PICObject {
    public $id;
    public $fileName;
    public $thumbLink;
    public $fullLink;
    public $title;
    public $subTitle;

    function __construct($id, $fileName, $thumbLink, $fullLink, $title, $subTitle) {
      $this->$id = $id;
      $this->$fileName = $fileName;
      $this->$thumbLink = $thumbLink;
      $this->$fullLink = $fullLink;
      $this->$title = $title;
      $this->$subTitle = $subTitle;
    }
  }
```

Now ideally I want to iterate this $pics array which should now contain several PICObjects and be able to access its fields:

```
foreach($pics as $picObj) {
   echo $picObj->$fileName;
}
```

However, this doesn't work. So how to do this? (I've tried it several ways but nothing really did what I was looking for)

Comment: check your syntax. `$this->id` not `$this->$id`, `echo $picObj->fileName;` not `echo $picObj->$fileName;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access the object attributes without the dollar sign, example:

```
foreach($pics as $picObj) {
   echo $picObj->fileName;
}
```

Comment: It's working now. Also I had to remove the dollar signs in my class e.g. $this->id not $this->$id as mentioned by the user Phpstall.

Answer (score 0):

try `array_push($pics, $newObj);` instead of `$pics[] = $newObj;`

edit:

can you post your `extract(value)` method?

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor class, you made a mistake

$this->$id = $id is wrong

$this->id = $id is correct

same for all other variables

Comment: This fixed it in combination with also accessing the object attributes without $.